# Limit write access to Firebase email user

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Let's say I've created a fresh `Email / Password` user for my Firebase collection called `bob@example.com`

How do I now limit the write access to anything in that collection to specifically this user?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}

...?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to get a bit more specific to get anything more helpful than the [security rules documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html). But to answer your question, let's say you wanted to limit your entire Firebase write access to Bob:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.email == 'bob@example.com'"
  }
}
```

Let's say you want to restrict an `item` collection in your Firebase just to Bob:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "items": {
      ".write": "auth.email == 'bob@example.com'"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that. Thanks for linking docs! So the `auth` object is a scope accessible within the `rules` and `items` is a handle in some part of your collection object? What happens if you have `items.something.items` ? --- Or is assumed that `items` in this example is starting from the parent node.

Comment: Yes `auth` is available in the rules; `items` was just an example parent node directly under your Firebase root (where only Bob could store `item` objects). The `"rules"` will match the structure of your data starting at the root, so if you had Bob's data at `/items/something/items` you'd have `"rules":{"items":{"something":{"items": "auth.email == "bob@example.com"}}}`. Anyway yeah give the docs a browse.

Comment: I have a good follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821571/persistent-authentication-states-firebase