# persistent authentication states Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

Lets say I've configured my write rules to a specific `email` :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.email == 'example@example.com'"
  }
}
```

And I login in using the `angularFireAuth` service:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", "angularFireAuth", function($scope, $rootScope, angularFireAuth) {

    var ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/");
    angularFireAuth.initialize(ref, {scope: $scope, name: "user"});

    $scope.cred = {};

    $scope.signin = function() {

        angularFireAuth.login('password', {
            email: $scope.cred.user,
            password: $scope.cred.password,
            rememberMe: true
        });
    }
}]);
```

I have a `newCtrl` that I use to add new items to my collection:

```
.controller('newCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", "angularFireCollection", function($scope, $rootScope, angularFireCollection) {

    var ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.items = angularFireCollection(ref);
}]);
```

When I invoke `items.add()` in my view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.name" />
<input type="text" ng-model="item.desc" />
<button ng-click="items.add(item)">submit</button>
```

I recieve a `Not Authorized` response even **after I've successfully logged in** through the `loginCtrl`

- How do I *create* a persistent authentication state across my entire application after **logging in**?
- How do I *remove* a persistent authentication state across my entire application after **logging out**?

Comment: Can you post your security rules?

Comment: Are you using the right Firebase url? This [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/hiattp/jqu5e/2/) for me.

Comment: Sorry that will be unhelpful without the auth credentials, use `example@example.com` as the email and `example` as the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your authentication state is session-based, not dependent on your controller scope, so you already have a "persistent authentication state" across your application.

There must be something else going on with your code that is generating that error, but as far as your question goes, you can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hiattp/jqu5e/2/) using `example@example.com` as the email and `example` as the password.

I matched your security rules as well, so if you login instead as `test@example.com` with password `test` you won't be able to create `items`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together. I assumed sessions were persistent across muiltiple tabs. I will follow up with a different question because I don't want to change goal posts from this current question. But you are right if you are on the same tab this example will absolutely work.

Comment: Yeah if it helps I think the session _is_ persistent, but the auth _events_ are local. It seems like we need a `/.info/authenticated` ref to manage authentication the same way you manage [presence](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell angularFireAuth broadcasts the login events from the $rootscope. You can set things to happen `.$on('angularFireAuth:login',function(event){...})`, or `.$on('angularFireAuth:logout',function(event){...})`, or `.$on('angularFireAuth:error',function(event,error){...})`. With this in mind you may want something like:

```
.controller('newCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", "angularFireCollection", function($scope, $rootScope, angularFireCollection) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.items = angularFireCollection(ref);
    $scope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', function(){
        $scope.addItem=function(item){
            $scope.items.add(item);
        };
    });
}]);
```

.. Which should ensure that the user authentication event occurs before the function is assigned to the $scope.

Comment: or whatever @hiattp says.. He's very helpful.